# 404 the requested resource is not available on a very simple servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've been stuck with this problem the whole morning and I can't seem to understand why.

This is my servlet. Very simple:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class hello
 */
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class hello extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public hello() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().write("test");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I start my tomcat server, and go to http://localhost:8080/testh/hello I receive the error message:
HTTP Status 404 - /testh/hello

Why? The server is started, and I have this specific servlet /hello running under the project "testh". I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: please share your web.xml

Comment: Check your deployment assembly if everything is deploying correctly, server class should be in `webapps/testh/WEB-INF/classes/hello.class` in tomcat. Also, name your classes staring with big letter like `Hello`.

Comment: It often helps enormously to read error messages carefully (see also the server logs).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [http://localhost:8080/hello](http://localhost:8080/login)

Because all you project is under the root

> /

And then you have mapping `/hello`

Also if you need exactly `http://localhost:8080/testh/hello` you should deploy app using path **/testh** and then HTTP call will route you to **/testh/hello** because your servlet path is **/hello** + app path **/testh**

Comment: His project name is `testh` and it needs to be included in a path, so just `http://localhost:8080/hello` shouldn't work.